# Scaled image not saving when cropped actionscript-3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When i try to save a cropped image that i have scaled, my save function ceases to work, but works perfectly fine when the image is not scaled. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
var loada = new Loader();
loada.load(new URLRequest("img_one.jpg"));
loada.x = 205;
loada.y = 110;
loada.cacheAsBitmap = true;
loada.scaleX = 1.5;


function toCrop():void 
{
    //Matrix to holder the area to be cropped
    var maskRect = loada.mask.getBounds(loada);
    //Matrix of image to be cropped
    var imgMatrix= loada.mask.transform.matrix;
    //Cropped image
    var myCroppedImage:Bitmap = crop(maskRect, imgMatrix, loada.mask.width, loada.mask.height, loada );

    var m:Matrix = myCroppedImage.transform.matrix;

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    //Set jpg quality of the image to be export 1-100
    var myEncoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    //Create jpg to be exported
    var pngSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (loada.mask.width, loada.mask.height, true, 0x00000000);
    pngSource.draw(myCroppedImage, m);
    //Create byte array to hold jpg data
    var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(pngSource);
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    //Send image to the server to be saved
    var savePNG:URLRequest = new URLRequest(glo.bal.base_url+"save_png.php?r="+glo.bal.fb_id+glo.bal.image_extension);
    savePNG.requestHeaders.push(header);
    savePNG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    savePNG.data = byteArray;
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doNothing1);
    urlLoader.load(savePNG);
}

function doNothing1(e:Event):void
{
    trace ( e );
}

function crop( rect, matrix, _width:Number, _height:Number, displayObject:DisplayObject):Bitmap 
{
    //Create cropped image
    var croppedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( _width, _height, true, 0x00000000), PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );
    croppedBitmap.bitmapData.draw(displayObject, matrix , null, null, rect, true );
    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: scroll down its at the bottom

Comment: try adding myCroppedImage to the stage to confirm your crop operation is successful.

Comment: you see the thing is, is that it only breaks if i scale the image, if i set the scale to one, it works... anything higher and it breaks...

Answer (score 0):

In your crop method, have you tried drawing it without passing the original DisplayObject's transform matrix? Seems to me it shouldn't need the transform matrix passed, especially since you want to copy the scaled version of the DisplayObject as-is.

Also, in your crop method, it seems a little backwards to create the bitmap before drawing the displayobject you want to copy ( I don't think this is what is messing it up but it might be worth a look ...)

I'd do:

```
var bmd:BitmapData  = new BitmapData (_width, _height, true, 0x00000000);
bmd.draw (displayObject, null, null, null, rect, true);
return new Bitmap (bmd, PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true);
```